Using AI assistants in virtual meetings
As of Friday I became aware of otter.ai as it was used in one of my online interviews. I'm not seeking legal advice about the situation but it has certainly raised some big questions for me on the legal implications of using AI tools in this way in general.
There are a number of problems I see here:

I never consented to this. I saw the bot but I didn't know what it was and had no time to research because, well, it's an interview
To later access the transcript it generated (which, at the time, I didn't know it was doing), I had to give the app access to my personal calendar
It misquotes me during the interview at numerous points including getting my previous employer's name wrong, so this is not just subjective on my part
It contains at least one screenshot of me, now clearly stored on their servers. I stopped reviewing it after that point so I don't know just how much of my conversation it retained - I just wanted the app out of my calendar

I find myself very upset about this, particularly as I was discussing detailed parts of my past work for other companies, which is now both misquoted and presumably stored on a 3rd party server.
I don't believe for one second that this was malicious but when I look at this now - does this contravene GDPR and is it a potential legal issue that companies could innocently stumble into?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

united-kingdom

High-level overview: there may be GDPR violations here. The relevant issues are:

Was your consent informed?
Was access to your calendar needed?
Are you allowed to have the incorrect information rectified?
Was the purpose of the information that they are storing clearly explained (including the screenshot(s) that you mention)?

It is important to note post-Brexit, the EU GDPR has been retained but, slightly modified under the Data Protection Act 2018. When I refer to GDPR below, I am referring to UK GDPR.

The company itself can be held responsible for GDPR breaches if they have not ensured that the AI tool is GDPR compliant. They may also be in breach if they have not informed and acquired the consent of those being interviewed. On the subject of sensitive data, which you allude to providing, it may be the case that the company is required to conduct a Data Protection Impact Assessment (DPIA). Below I have addressed your specific concerns:
Consent: Under GDPR, consent to the processing of personal data must be freely given, informed, specific, and unambiguous. While it is true that you provided consent to the processing of the disclosed information in your interview, it could be argued that this consent was not informed as you were unaware of their use of Otter.ai (see Article 7 and Recital 32 of the GDPR for more information).

In 2020, the Norwegian Consumer Council and NOYB filed complaints against Grindr for sharing users' personal data with third parties without valid consent. The Norwegian Data Protection Authority fined Grindr €6.5 million.

Access to your calendar: The issue is no longer one of consent. Instead, GDPR mandates that organisations must only collect data necessary for their purposes. If they do not have a good reason for needing calendar access, then there is an argument to be made that there has been a breach here (see Article 5(1)(c) of the GDPR for an explanation of the Data Minimisation Principle).

Explicitly, Article 5(1)(c) defines the Data Minimisation Principle in the following way: "Personal data shall be adequate, relevant and limited to what is necessary in relation to the purposes for which they are processed (data minimisation)”

Accuracy: The accuracy of any information recorded in an interview always has a possibility for error - whether AI-generated or due to human mistake. GDPR does include a right to rectification. This means that you should be allowed to request corrections to inaccurate data (under Article 16 of the GDPR).

The Data Protection Act 2018 states that personal information must be "incorrect or misleading as to any matter of fact" for this aspect of the UK GDPR to apply. The factual requirement is particularly important here.

Data Storage: GDPR requires that you are informed of a) what data is stored, b) for how long it will be stored, and c) the purpose behind storing the data (see Article 13 and Article 14 of the GDPR for information directly from you and indirectly obtained by Otter.ai respectively). Additionally, storage on third-party servers requires adherence to data transfer rules. The exact nature of these rules depend on the country that those servers are in. For example, there are Standard Contractual Clauses (SCCs) safeguards that may apply if the servers are in the US.

There have been numerous high-profile cases of GDPR violations relating to issues of transparency. In 2019, France's data protection authority, CNIL, fined Google €50 million for insufficient transparency and lack of valid consent in personal data processing for ad personalisation. In 2020, H&M faced a €35.3 million fine in Germany for unlawfully surveilling employees. In 2020, the UK's Information Commissioner's Office (ICO) found that Experian had violated GDPR by processing personal data without sufficient transparency. Experian collected data from various sources and used it for marketing purposes without adequately informing individuals.


Thank you. On the flip side of the legality of these services, I think it's worth noting the public perception of the way this app operates. Indeed, I declined my second interview over this incident. There's also this and this

And just to be clear, I'm not expecting you to include that into the answer, it's just an addendum that isn't strictly legal but extends the angles of consideration for this kind of internal review about the use of these tools

united-kingdom
The detail in the description of the circumstances is insufficient to be definitive about whether this organisation behaved lawfully or unlawfully.
Certainly there are "personal data" within the meaning of GDPR; it seems there is "special category" data too (the image of the interviewee's face); there is "transfer" to a third party (otter.ai), and (I think) to another country (the USA, where otter.ai is based). Therefore the UK GDPR and Data Protection Act 2018 apply, in which there are many rules.
What is not evident in the description is whether the organisation was forthcoming and transparent about its collection and processing of personal data, the purposes for which this is done, and the "lawful basis" (i.e. legal reason) for each purpose. If it wasn't - if the interviewee could not be said to have been informed of any of this - then on the face of it the organisation behaved unlawfully.
The interviewee - the "data subject" - has a "right to be informed" (GDPR Article 13) about all of that and more. The bare minimum is to provide a privacy policy or privacy notice. In some circumstances, particularly the more sensitive the data or activity, the organisation ought to be more proactive about bringing this information to the attention of the data subject at the relevant time.
This seems to be the first item to address.
Quoting from GDPR Article 12:

The controller shall take appropriate measures to provide any information referred to in Articles 13 and 14 and any communication under Articles 15 to 22 and 34 relating to processing to the data subject in a concise, transparent, intelligible and easily accessible form, using clear and plain language, in particular for any information addressed specifically to a child. The information shall be provided in writing, or by other means, including, where appropriate, by electronic means. When requested by the data subject, the information may be provided orally, provided that the identity of the data subject is proven by other means. ..

Quoting from Article 13(1):


Where personal data relating to a data subject are collected from the data subject, the controller shall, at the time when personal data
are obtained, provide the data subject with all of the following
information: ...

(c) the purposes of the processing for which the personal data are
intended

Two key points about purposes (Article 5 Principles relating to processing of personal data):
The personal data is "collected for specified, explicit and legitimate purposes and not further processed in a manner that is incompatible with those purposes;" and "adequate, relevant and limited to what is necessary in relation to the purposes for which they are processed (‘data minimisation’)". That is to say, the organisation must tell you what is the purpose specifically and the collection and processing must be proportionate to this purpose - the system is disproportionate if the purpose can be reasonably achieved with less.
A real UK case was a leisure gym group that was deemed by the Information Commissioner's Office to have gone overboard on using facial recognition technology (FRT) and fingerprint scanning to monitor employee attendance, because the company wouldn't offer an alternative system to employees who were not comfortable with this and couldn't demonstrate that it could not achieve the same purpose by using ordinary ID cards.

as well as the legal basis for the processing;

There are six lawful bases (Article 6); "consent" is but one of these although the others do not seem relevant/appropriate in the circumstances described.
If the lawful basis is "consent", it must be a "freely given, specific, informed and unambiguous indication of the data subject's wishes by which he or she, by a statement or by a clear affirmative action, signifies agreement to the processing of personal data relating to him or her" (Article 4(11)). The organisation must be able to show that the data subject consented to this processing. (Article 7 conditions for consent.)

(d) where the processing is based on point (f) of Article 6(1), the
legitimate interests pursued by the controller or by a third party;

Another answer mentions the lawful basis of "legitimate interest". This paragraph (d) means that if the organisation relies on legitimate interest it must inform the data subject what specifically is the interest, it can't simply say "we have a legitimate interest". Furthermore the implication is that this interest outweighs the interests of the data subject, which is or ought to be a high bar to reach.

(e) the recipients or categories of recipients of the personal data,
if any;
(f) where applicable, the fact that the controller intends to transfer
personal data to a third country or international organisation and the
existence or absence of [F1relevant adequacy regulations under section
17A of the 2018 Act], or in the case of transfers referred to in
Article 46 or 47, or the second subparagraph of Article 49(1),
reference to the appropriate or suitable safeguards and the means by
which to obtain a copy of them or where they have been made available.

Transfers have a whole Chapter dedicated to them, Chapter V. Again the organisation must tell the data subject about all of this ahead of time. "We use this software, it is made by company X, which stores the data in country Y" etc.
The special category data - the facial image - deserves a mention of its own because it has its own conditions for processing (Article 9). Again the only relevant condition seems to be consent, unless the image was "manifestly made public by the data subject" (e.g. it is a Linkedin profile photo).

Do you mean otter.ai?

Also, what's the basis for the advice to ask “Do you consent to this interview being transcribed by this software?" If you need to track consent, would that be enough? Conversely, if you rely another basis for the processing, has there been any case where a privacy notice wasn't enough?

I have been running interviews for decade – as a research tool, not hiring interviews – and always explain exactly what I am collecting and why, even if there is no recording. I certainly agree that is is the ethical thing to do but does it serve any purpose from a GDPR point of view? I feel this answer like a lot of the discussion around this question confuses what's required by the GDPR and what feels right in the situation.

@Relaxed "[I] always explain exactly what I am collecting and why ... does it serve any purpose from a GDPR point of view?" Yes, it fulfills Articles 12 (The controller shall take appropriate measures to provide any information referred to in Articles 13 ...." and 13 (Information to be provided where personal data are collected from the data subject), etc.

@Relaxed "Also, what's the basis for..." I referred to Article 7(1) "Where processing is based on consent, the controller shall be able to demonstrate that the data subject has consented to processing of his or her personal data." When 'you' want to rely on consent, imagine you may have to persuade a regulator or a court that the data subject consented "by a statement or by a clear affirmative action, signifies agreement". What evidence will you be able to provide?

When I rely on consent for a research interviews, I rely on actual paper consent forms or an electronic signature obtained prior to starting the recording. The plain language explanation and verbal check is something I do for ethical reasons and to make sure the person has actually read and understood the document. It's far from obvious to me that just saying "Do you consent to this interview being transcribed by this software?" is enough, that's certainly not the advice I received. It also seems far from sufficient to satisfy article 13, so I am asking again: What is your advice based on?

But what I do is irrelevant, I am not saying that's not a good idea to ask again, I am just saying you should not confuse people about the reasons why you might do it. This advice seems like a weird in-between thing based more on what you feel is reasonable than anything else. It's unnecessary for a business that may not rely on consent at all and almost certainly has to provide more extensive info in writing somewhere but not enough if it's the only way you have to inform the person and track consent.

Thanks for addressing the two issues I raised, I removed by downvote.

eu
The precise details of how this tool works may be a bit of a red herring. Ultimately, a business will inevitably process a lot of very personal data over the course of an application and this is just one of the tools they use. Some businesses might still do everything with offline MS Office files but any cloud-oriented tool stack or modern Application Tracking Systems will involve multiple tools and data hosted on third-party servers, many of them in the US, and face a lot of legal issues. Otter does seem to have a rather poor culture when it comes to privacy but don't assume the stuff you don't see is any better (ATS in particular seem just as error prone when parsing and filtering resumes)!
From a data protection point of view, the business you interviewed with may have collected consent when you first submitted your application or plausibly invoke another basis for processing your data including article 6(1)(b) “taking steps at the request of the data subject prior to entering into a contract” or 6(1)(f) legitimate interest. As the hiring process necessarily involves processing a lot of personal data, they definitely need to spell out that basis in writing. It would be equally true if they didn't use otter.ai and merely kept resumes on a cloud drive but it's not obvious that they should ask for consent separately for each tool or refrain from transcribing interviews as part of that process.
Of course, their obligations do not stop there, they do need to keep track of all the data they collected about you, take steps to minimize and secure it, allow you to correct mistakes, respond to data access requests, etc. It's now become common to receive notifications from businesses asking for permission to retain application data, usually about one year after the original application. If you decline to consent to any further retention, the transcript then ought to be deleted with everything else, except perhaps some bare bones information they think they can retain longer.
Regarding Otter specifically, they recently added some “assistant” features (like an automated summary) and started talking even more about “AI” in their marketing material but at the core it's a transcription tool which has been around for years. Transcripts are not completely new and it seems that it would be no more (and no less) problematic than a “dumb“ recording or your interviewer's notes. Even resumes (which, in some countries, tend to include pictures) or annotation from recruiters are far from innocuous. In other words, this is not a legal grey area, any business processing personal data from job applicants has a number of obligations under the GDPR and hopefully reviews processes and vendors with this in mind.
Some of these obligations may be harder to satisfy while using otter.ai (like many businesses, their website name checks the GDPR but provides very little specific info so I would take that with a grain of salt) and it's unclear whether this potential employer is really prepared for it but you don't really know if you haven't checked their privacy policy or gone through the deletion process.

With respect this answer may come across as a bit blasé. The question is whether the behaviour is lawful, not how common it is. Also, the organisation is obliged to tell the data subject about each and every purpose of collecting and processing data and its lawful basis. If it claims "legitimate interest" it must tell the data subject what is the legitimate interest - and the implication is that this interest outweighs the interests of the data subject, which ought to be a high bar.

This doesn't really address the concerns raised in the original question, which are not just about the recording but the automation, the errors, and the retention of those errors.

@barbecue It doesn't seem to be the angle the OP chose. I mentioned errors in the answer, you ought to be able to ask for corrections but the OP asked about the lack of consent and the sensitive nature of the information. The point of my answer is that those are a given in a recruitment process and I don't see how the automation changes anything to the calculation. And just to be clear: I hate these assistants and think they shouldn't be used. But I also think assuming the GDPR requires granular consent for everything or can be used as leverage to deal with this is mistaken.

@Lag You're right that listing the purpose and basis for the processing is necessary in any case but I disagree that the balance with the interests of the data subject is a high bar to meet in this case. Like I wrote, you could even plausibly invoke  6(1)(b). The OP is volunteering all this information precisely to support the hiring decision and unlike all the predatory ad-based business models, there is zero evidence it is being used for anything else.

That's also the reason I mention ATS and all the rest: It's not only common, it shows that processing application requires processing a lot of highly sensitive information, with or without AI assistant.

@Relaxed That's why I specifically said "not just about." OP's concern is clearly not that someone recorded the interview, or that a transcript of what was said might be kept. Clearly the OP's concerns are with the requirement to consent to allowing a third party service to access his calendar, the creation of a permanent AI-generated record, and the fact that that record is factually incorrect with no easy way to correct it.

I don't think " this is not a legal grey area" can really be applied to any third-party AI-powered service.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
